# Batching trigger Lambda on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm having a table as below

```
Key                                 | Value
---------------------------------------------------
Client_123_UNIQUE_ID                | s3://abc.txt
Client_123_UNIQUE_ID                | s3://xyz.txt
Client_456_UNIQUE_ID                | s3://qaz.txt              
Client_456_UNIQUE_ID                | s3://qwe.txt
Client_789_UNIQUE_ID                | s3://asd.txt
Client_789_UNIQUE_ID                | s3://zxc.txt
```

The data will be inserted consistently to this table from a AWS Lambda function. (maybe millions items)

I have an use case which I need to have a trigger when there is 100 items available in the table to perform some batch processing.
In other mean, as soon as we have 100 new items created in this table, I would like to have a trigger to Lambda function to perform a batch processing on 100 items.

When I research, it seems DynamoDB Stream can support Batch but I'm not pretty clear based on documentation.

> Lambda reads records in batches and invokes your function to process
>   records from the batch.
>
> Lambda polls shards in your DynamoDB Streams stream for records at a
>   base rate of 4 times per second. When records are available, Lambda
>   invokes your function and waits for the result. If processing
>   succeeds, Lambda resumes polling until it receives more records.
>
> If your function returns an error, Lambda retries the batch until
>   processing succeeds or the data expires. Until the issue is resolved,
>   no data in the shard is processed. Handle any record processing errors
>   in your code to avoid stalled shards and potential data loss.

Could you please help me to clarify documentation or advice me the approach which we use DynamoDB Stream is correct one for this use case?

If I'm explaining my question is not good enough, please put comments so I can clarify more.

Comment: were you able to solve this? if yes, how?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes , I did it already

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`BatchSize`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping-batchsize) when declaring the mapping between the stream and Lambda. The max size is 10000 items.

Comment: Suppose, I set the batch size is 100 and then if there is no enough 100 items, is the lambda receiving the trigger with records?

Comment: Yes. It's the maximum size. The Lambda function can be invoked also with less than the full batch size.

Comment: I would like to understand more about batch, suppose im having 100 as batch size and there is 140 items inserted to dynamo db, how many times lambda will get triggered?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.

Comment: I have tried by myself, the batch number varies alot

Comment: @NghiaDo In that case, the number of batch invocations would be 2. First batch of 100 items and second batch of 40 items. Later 40 items are sent as batch to Lambda assuming timeout of batch occures.

Comment: Following the official docs here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html maximum batch size is currently set to 10000

Comment: Cheers, updated.